# Auto-authenticate to a domain network share

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, network-share, windows-authentication

Hoping one of you can help me out with a network share issue I'm having.

I have a domain and three servers and NAS on it. The NAS has a network share that is password protected and uses Active Directory to authenticate. If I try to access the share from two of the three computers in an explorer window:

```
\\nas_ip\share
```

it works just fine. On the third server, however, it prompts me for a username and password. If I type in a user and password it connects just fine, however, I want it to auto-authenticate based on the AD user currently logged in. I am using the same AD user on all three servers, and only the one has a connection problem.

This is my first foray into Windows Server and AD, so I'm sure I have a setting wrong somewhere on the 3rd server, but I don't know what it is. I don't remember making any changes to that one server that I didn't make to the others, but apparently I did. Any help that you guys can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your NAS authenticating? Kerberos? If so, do you have an appropriate kerberos ticket on the troublesome server? You can check this with `klist.exe` Does `whoami /groups` provide the same output on the troublesome server when logged in as the same user on the other two that work?

Comment: It's on the domain, too, and uses AD to authenticate (2nd paragraph).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. There are multiple authentication methods available on an AD domain, including Kerberos and NTLMv2 among others.

Comment: Apologies.  Please forgive my naivety; this is my first time really using Windows Server.  I have asked the NAS4Free devs for the method, but I think it may be Kerberos.  Also the output of *whoami /groups* is the same on all servers.

Comment: Did you try looking at the "security" log of your Windows machines? All of the clients and the DCs. Look for "failures" with timestamps matching the times you try to access the share.  
Also see if your NAS box has some security log - most *nix ones keep it in their main logfile

Comment: Hi @Nitz thanks for the suggestions.  I checked the logs of all 3 machines and I see no entries for anything related to my NAS, though it's possible I'm not looking in the right area (Event Viewer > Windows Logs).  Also checked my NAS's logs and see no connection information from any of the 3 servers.

Comment: Ended up solving my problem with help from http://serverfault.com/a/563005/175650 Turns out I had a credential for an old user/pass combo stored.  I deleted the credential and rebooted, and everything is working.  Huzzah!

Comment: Why don't you connect the NAS volume to the server via iSCSI and share the folders from there? That way, you don't need to fiddle around with that.

Answer (score -1):

NAS4Free features iSCSI Targets, so what you want to do is

1. Create an iSCSI target on the NAS.
2. Start the iSCSI-Initiator on the Server and add the iSCSI volume from the NAS.
3. Go to disk management and put the volume in on-line mode.
4. Share the volume or folders from within Windows.

If server and NAS are at the same site, this is the best solution for what you want to achieve.